# Is there a wireframe app that produces/exports HTML?

Tags: webapp-rec, html

I know it seems kind of counter productive to what a wireframe app should be, but I know some of my non-technical friends like how easy it is to use a wireframe app, but don't know HTML and would love to be able to get a basic page up that looks similar to what the wireframe is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try http://www.jumpchart.com/. It can export projects as HTML pages. Highly recommended.

Comment: Looks exactly like what I was looking for